# How to get cocos2dx into a wxGLCanvas of wxWidgets

Tags: cocos2d-x, wxwidgets

I'm trying to create a level editor for my futur game, to do that I need to get cocos2dx scene showing in a wxGLCanvas of the wxWidgets library.

How to link the wxGLCanvas with cocos2d::GLView ?

What I've done :

Created a class ccwxGLView that inherits from GLView:

```
class ccwxGLView : public cocos2d::GLView
{
    ccwxGLCanvas* mGLCanvas;

public:
    ccwxGLView(ccwxGLCanvas* canvas) {
        setGLCanvas(canvas);
    }

    virtual ~ccwxGLView(void) {}

    static ccwxGLView* create(ccwxGLCanvas* canvas) {
        auto ret = new (std::nothrow) ccwxGLView(canvas);
        if(ret) {
            ret->autorelease();
            return ret;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    void setGLCanvas(ccwxGLCanvas* canvas) {
        mGLCanvas = canvas;
    }
    ccwxGLCanvas* getGLCanvas() {
        return mGLCanvas;
    }

    HWND getWin32Window() {
        return mGLCanvas->GetParent()->GetHWND();
    }

    /** Force destroying EGL view, subclass must implement this method. */
    virtual void end() {
        mGLCanvas->Close();
        wxDELETE(mGLCanvas);
        mGLCanvas = nullptr;
    }

    /** Get whether opengl render system is ready, subclass must implement this method. */
    virtual bool isOpenGLReady() {
        return (mGLCanvas && mGLCanvas->IsShown());
    }

    /** Exchanges the front and back buffers, subclass must implement this method. */
    virtual void swapBuffers() {
        mGLCanvas->SwapBuffers();
    }

    virtual void setIMEKeyboardState(bool open) {}

    virtual bool windowShouldClose() {
        return (mGLCanvas == nullptr);
    }
};
```

Created a class that inherits from wxGLCanvas :

```
class ccwxGLCanvas : public wxGLCanvas
{
    wxGLContext*    m_context;

public:
    ccwxGLCanvas(wxFrame* parent, int* args)
        : wxGLCanvas(parent, wxID_ANY, args, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
    {
        m_context = new wxGLContext(this);
    }

    virtual ~ccwxGLCanvas() { delete m_context; }

    void resized(wxSizeEvent& evt) {
        Refresh();
    }

    void render(wxPaintEvent& evt) {
        cocos2d::Director* director = cocos2d::Director::getInstance();
        if(director != nullptr && director->getRunningScene() != nullptr)
            director->drawScene();
    }
};
```

In the AppDelegate I modified the glView initialization by :

```
if(!glview) {
    glview = ccwxGLView::create(mGLCanvas);
    director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}
```

And on the app init function, I wrote something like this :

```
wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
frame = new wxFrame((wxFrame *)NULL, -1,  wxT("Hello GL World"), wxPoint(50,50), wxSize(400,200));

int args[] = {WX_GL_RGBA, WX_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, WX_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16, 0};

glPane = new ccwxGLCanvas( (wxFrame*) frame, args);
sizer->Add(glPane, 1, wxEXPAND);

frame->SetSizer(sizer);
frame->SetAutoLayout(true);

frame->Show();

ccApp = new AppDelegate();
ccApp->setGLCanvas(glPane);
ccApp->applicationDidFinishLaunching();
```

When I run, a wxFrame (window) is shown and the app crashes immediately.
Call stack :

> libcocos2d.dll!cocos2d::Renderer::setupVBO() Line 352   C++
>       libcocos2d.dll!cocos2d::Renderer::setupBuffer() Line 285    C++
>       libcocos2d.dll!cocos2d::Renderer::initGLView() Line 272 C++
>       libcocos2d.dll!cocos2d::Director::setOpenGLView(cocos2d::GLView * openGLView) Line 394  C++
>       editor.exe!AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() Line 44 C++
>       editor.exe!EditorApp::OnInit() Line 25  C++
>       wxbase30ud_vc_custom.dll!wxAppConsoleBase::CallOnInit() Line 93 C++
>       wxbase30ud_vc_custom.dll!wxEntryReal(int & argc, wchar_t * * argv) Line 479 C++
>       wxbase30ud_vc_custom.dll!wxEntry(int & argc, wchar_t * * argv) Line 188 C++

Comment: Well, you have gone down the road I would have suggested. All I can put forward at this point is some better debug info would help: Add the ./cocos2d/cocos/2d/libcocos2d.vcxproj explicitly to your project and remove the static lib references

Comment: I got it to work, I looked to the GLViewImpl provided by cocos2d-x and modified each piece of code that needs to be changed, I dont know why but the above code I posted needed a call to glewInit to work. And I had to move the initialization on the GLViewWx to the wxGLCanvas first draw event, because glewInit failed when I used it in the constructor of the class.

Comment: glewInit requires an OpenGL context to work, which requires a created window, which only happens long after construction when GLView::init() is called. And glewInit loads the various gl extension methods that have been added to OpenGL, so is required in any app that needs to use any functionality added since OpenGL 1.1